# Problema com origin/master no git ao tentar realizar commit

Tags: git, github

Estou tentanto realizar um commit para atualizar um projeto no git,porém sempre acabo tendo o mesmo problema,ele não realiza pois alega que o origin/master estão com diferentes commits cada um.Segui o que o programa diz pra fazer,porém não resultou em nada, continua dando o mesmo erro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Voce tem alterações que vc não fez o stage ainda, ai vc não consegue fazer o commit

1. Primeiro da um `git add .`
2. Depois vc faz seu commit normalmente e da um `git pull`
3. ai então vc poderá da um `git push` normalmente

acredito que isso resolverá seu problema.

Answer (score 0):

Você primeiro tem que adicionar os arquivos que quer adicionar ao repositório com seu commit, depois que você escreve o commit e da o git push.

Você pode dar um `git status` para ver os arquivos que foram modificados;

Depois você pode usar `git add [filename]` para adicionar arquivos exclusivos, ou `git add --all .` para adicionar todos os arquivos que foram modificados;

Agora você escreve o commit usando `git commit -m "seu commit"`;

Agora é só usar `git push` ou `git push <link do seu repositório>`.